# Trying to implement Multi Level Push Menu from http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs on a site

Tags: javascript, perl

Here is where I am trying implement the Multi Level Push Menu in a page powered by Perl: 
http://find-where.com/cgi-bin/perl_modules/installed_modules.cgi

I am not a JS expert but do know how to use/implement simple JS; but in this case, I am stuck.  I think it has something to do with jQuery which I am not well versed in.

My problem is that the links are not working.  I want the links to open in an iframe within the page.

But, if I do 'open in new tab/window' on the very same links, they work just fine!

But clicking on the links not working!

Comment: Have you used the js console in your browser to see whether there are any errors emitted?

Comment: Put all your `script` tags at the end of your body. And put the JQuery at the top of them.

Comment: Thanks.  In the FF console, I am getting this error:  '$' is not defined in file installed_modules.js line 3

Comment: Patrick J.S, Followed your instructions.  still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current set up, javascript is being run before jQuery has been loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* lots of stuff snipped */
});
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This gives you the error

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

To fix that, you need to load jQuery *before* the code that refers to `$` (`$` is an alias for jQuery) starts.

At the end of the document content, above the `</body>` tag, add the jQuery script source, and then the rest of your javascript. Ideally, you should have a local version of jQuery in case the CDN version doesn't load. Let's say you have a copy in `/mlpushmenu/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`; you can check whether `window.jQuery` is defined (i.e. whether jQuery has loaded from the CDN), and if it hasn't, add the source of your local jQuery file to the page. Add the other libraries, and then the code to load links in the iframe.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery ||
    document.write('<script src="/mlpushmenu/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mlpushmenu/jquery.multilevelpushmenu.min.js"></script>
<!-- any other js libraries here -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
    onItemClick: function() {
        // First argument is original event object
        var event = arguments[0],
            // Second argument is menu level object containing clicked item (<div> element)
            $menuLevelHolder = arguments[1],
            // Third argument is clicked item (<li> element)
            $item = arguments[2],
            // Fourth argument is instance settings/options object
            options = arguments[3];

        // Anchor href
        var itemHref = $item.find( 'a:first' ).attr( 'href' );
        // Redirecting the page: replace the `src` URL for the iframe showPerlDoc
        // with the URL of the item.
        $('#showPerlDoc').attr('src', itemHref);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/va3Lm6nh/) with the code working.

Comment: Allen, now it's empty: nothing in the menu!!

Comment: btw, the menu shows up if you remove the `<script type="text/javascript" src="/mlpushmenu/demo/basichtml/basichtml.js"></script>`, which is probably redundant with what jquery.multilevelpushmenu.min.js does.

Comment: I got that block of code from their original site.  Nevertheless, I removed that whole block.  Now, the menu does show up, but links are still not working.

Comment: if I remove the ..basichtml.js.. menu does not show up properly, just the raw ul stuff shows up...

Comment: Also, the URL you've got in your iframe isn't retrieving the pod correctly - it should be `<iframe id="showPerlDoc" src="http://find-where.com/cgi-bin/perl_modules/installed_modules.cgi?module=CGI/Apache.pm"  height="1800" width="100%"></iframe>`

Comment: Yeah, I put that block of code back in installed_modules.cgi

Comment: I've updated my answer and made a JSFiddle with the code working in it. If this solves your problem, please click the tick and the up arrow next to the answer to show your appreciation. Thank you!

Comment: I made the above changes.  I also validated using validator.w3c.  There still seems to be some problem!  The JSFiddle works fine on Chrome.  But the MLPM does not show up until I manually initiate by dragging on it; and works fine after that first initiation!

Comment: The W3C validation was OK without errors.  Also removed the CDN for jquery

Comment: Thanks for all you hard work/efforts @i-alarmed-alien

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem by setting two parameters in mlpm init call to `false`:

```
preventItemClick: false,
preventGroupItemClick: false,
```